# ng-style working initally but not on variable update

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-style

I have a strange bug/behaviour when using ng-style with a variable, where it works on whatever value is set to it initially, but when I update the variable the view doesn't update the way it should. I can find similar questions but none in the exact same situation. I have(simplified):
a directive:

```
directives.directive('myAccordion', function{
  return {
   templateUrl: '/mytemplate.html';
   link: function($scope){
    'use-strict';
     scope.current_style '{\'max-height\':\'\'0px'}';
     scope.somefunc = function{
       isopen = !isopen;
       if(isopen){
         scope.current_style = '{\'max-height\':\'\'1000px'}';
       }else{
         scope.current_style = '{\'max-height\':\'\'0px'}'; 
     }
  };
```

and in the template html

```
etc etc
<div class="myclass" ng-style="{{current_style}}">
   <button ng-click="somefunc()"></button> 
</div>
etc
```

and so everything works fine including whatever I set current_style to be initially, and when showing the value of current_style it the variable does actually change to the correct text when the button is clicked and somefunc() is called, but the ng-style doesn't update and the div stays the same size.
I'm not sure what I've missed here.
Thanks for any help

Comment: You assign it to a 'global' variable `current_style`. Do `$scope.current_style = ..` instead. Also I don't think the curly brackets in the `ng-style="{{}}"` are necessary. You should also be aware that your `isOpen` variable is used as a global

Comment: Ok well it's over simplified code and the variables actually all belong to a object(made with an object constructor function) so in the actual code, current_style is part of an object which is then created on the scope (scope.accordion1 = new accordion) so thats not the issue, maybe I should  update the code to represent that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the object notation of `ng-style`:

```
scope.current_style = { 'max-height': '0px' };

scope.somefunc = function() {
    isopen = !isopen;
    if(isopen){
        scope.current_style["max-height"] = '1000px';
    } else {
        scope.current_style["max-height"] = '0px';
    }
}
```

And in your html:

```
<div class="myclass" ng-style="current_style">
    <button ng-click="somefunc()"></button> 
</div>
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zq6k3qd9/2/)

Comment: This has fixed it, thanks a bunch! Out of interest, any idea of the particular reason it wasn't working before?

Comment: I think it is because of your string notation, e.g. an object surrounded with quotes which just represents a string

Answer (score 0):

please try the following, it's a little cleaner

```
if(isopen){
  scope.height= 1000;
}else{
  scope.height= 0; 
}


<div class="myclass" ng-style="{'max-height' : height + 'px'}">
```

to have even cleaner code use the following:

```
scope.heignt = isopen ? 1000 : 0;
```

less code to maintain :)

Comment: Ok  that's a potentially cleaner way to do it but unfortunatley doesn't solve the problem (having just tried hoping it would)